# Scroll beyond last line in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

Is there a setting in WebStorm to allow scrolling past the last line, like the latest Visual Studio allows? I don't like having to keep like 20 new lines at the end of a file just so I can work in the middle of my screen.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Settings | Editor | General, Virtual Space | Show virtual space at the bottom of the file

Comment: This is the answer I wanted, but to disable, rather than enable. Disabling this option prevents files opening in a state where only the last line is visible and instead keeps the majority of the file in view at all times.